# capturing image and displaying

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gridview, android-image

I am trying to click images from camera and displaying them in gridview. I am using the below code but getting the "unfortunately camera has stopped working" error. please suggest

logcat:beginning of crash`**07-09 01:14:01.734    3873-3873/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sakshi.intel, PID: 3873
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sakshi.intel/com.example.sakshi.intel.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
     at com.example.sakshi.intel.MainActivity$ImageAdapter.getCount(MainActivity.java:89)
     at android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(GridView.java:201)
     at com.example.sakshi.intel.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)**`

using the below code:
activity_main.xml`

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="photo"
    android:onClick="takePicture"/>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></GridView>
```

`

```
MainActivity.java
```

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
private List<String> myList;  // String list that contains file paths to images
private GridView gridview;
private String mCurrentPhotoPath;  // File path to the last image captured

static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialize GridView
    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    // Initialize GridView Thumbnail Click Handler
        /*gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                // Send File Path to Image Display Activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImageDisplayActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("path", myList.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });*/
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return myList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 4;
        bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myList.get(position), bmOptions);

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        return imageView;
    }
}


private void takePicture()
{
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
    {
        File photoFile = null;
        try
        {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null)
        {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore. EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri. fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException
{
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format( new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_" ;
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File. createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        // Save Image To Gallery
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE );
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath );
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

        // Add Image Path To List
        myList.add( mCurrentPhotoPath);

        // Refresh Gridview Image Thumbnails
        gridview.invalidateViews();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the size of the list, `myList` in `getCount()`, inside `ImageAdapter` class.  And that is where the exception happened.

The exception occurred because `myList` is a null object.

Why is it null? possibly because in `myList.add( mCurrentPhotoPath);`  inside `onActivityResult`, the value of `mCurrentPhotoPath` might be null.

Add a check like this inside `onActivityResult` :

`if (mCurrentPhotoPath != null) {
     myList.add(mCurrentPhotoPath); 
} else {
     // can't access image file path.Show a toast or something. 
}`

Now, from my experience some phone manufactures return a file path, where as some return the bitmap of the image captured. I am not sure, some might return both. 
So just expecting to access file path of captured image won't help your app.

Comment: Raghav, what would you recommend to get all the clicked images in that session on screen?

Comment: Ok, I assume this is what you are trying to do : User uses your app and captures a photo from the the camera intent from your app . Your app gets that photo and does some stuff. Right? or is it different?

Comment: Also which device are you using to test it? I used to get bitmaps in Samsung S4 and in some others filepath.

Comment: yes, but i am able to capture and retrieve single photo. I am struggling with multiple photos. how to click multiple images and get in my application